Wrong/truncated command gets pasted in terminal, while debugging python in VSCode
VSCode version: 1.89.0
Python debugger version: v2024.6.0  
OS: Windows 10

When debugging using the python debugger in VSCode, the command for debugging gets consistently pasted wrong in the terminal.
When debugging a file for the first time, the pasted command works as intended:
USER@LNWG6GMF0 MINGW64 D:/Microsoft VS Code
$  /usr/bin/env d:\\Miniconda\\envs\\coagfloc\\python.exe c:\\Users\\USER\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\\bundled\\libs\\debugpy\\adapter/../..\\debugpy\\launcher 61808 -- D:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Flocculatieexperimenten\\main.py 
$LAST FOUR CHARACTERS OF MY USERNAME$\\\\Desktop\\\\Flocculatieexperimenten\\\\main.py ;8eb223eb-d552-48b1-90d5-8c7a5710994cBackend QtAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.

Some strange text gets outputted in the console, though, but that does not affect execution.
If I then start debugging in the same console, stuff goes wrong:
USER@LNWG6GMF0 MINGW64 D:/Microsoft VS Code
$ ^C
(base) 
USER@LNWG6GMF0 MINGW64 D:/Microsoft VS Code
$ c\\python.exe c:\\Users\\USER\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\\bundled\\libs\\debugpy\\adapter/../..\\debugpy\\launcher 61822 -- D:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\Flocculatieexperimenten\\main.py
ain.py ;8eb223eb-d552-48b1-90d5-8c7a5710994cbash: c\python.exe: No such file or directory

A wrong command gets pasted in the python debug console terminal and nothing gets executed. I'm also not pressing CTRL-C, that's also automatic. VSCode then thinks it's hanging and gives me an error prompt, but the execution just never started.
Note that this is likely truncated as c\\python.exe are the last few characters of the path to the python executable in the environment.
My launch.json looks as follows:
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Python Debugger: Current file",
            "type": "debugpy",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}

I tried:

reinstalling VSCode, python, conda, python debugger extension
Installing previous versions of the above
changing the launch.json file to try to hardcode the command


potentially answered by https://stackoverflow.com/q/78281461/11107541 ?

why is there a MINGW64 in the terminal prompt
